# Как реализовать сетку с "захватыванием" к клетке?

Tags: python, pygame

Я разрабатываю игру на Pygame и у меня появилась проблема с созданием сетки, в которой, если нажать на одну из ячеек, то изображение будет появляться именно в центре ячейки.

Первая моя мысль состояла в том, чтобы создать несколько pygame.Rect, при нажатии на которые, изображения будут появляться именно там, где находится этот pygame.Rect. Но так, как размер сетки - 8x8, то приходится просто сделать 64 переменной, что, я думаю, не эффективно.

Если неясно, что я имею в виду, то я специально показал на изображении, как это должно быть реализовано.

[image: фотография]

код(код может показаться плохо-написанным, но это всё, что я могу):

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import os
import sys

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

motion = "stop"

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((512, 512))
pygame.display.set_caption('Main Menu - Limited Space, Endless Ideas')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

### Настраиваем директории ###
rootPath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
resourcesPath = os.path.join(rootPath, "resources")
texturesPath = os.path.join(resourcesPath, "textures")
playerPath = os.path.join(texturesPath, "player")
skinsPath = os.path.join(playerPath, "skins")

### Настраиваем пути текстур ###
ground512 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(texturesPath, "ground512x512.png"))
box = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(texturesPath, "normalbox.png"))
box = pygame.transform.scale(box, (64, 64))
boxSprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
boxSprite.image = box
boxSprite.rect = box.get_rect()

### Настраиваем шрифт ###
font1 = pygame.font.Font('font.ttf', 36)

grid1 = pygame.Rect((0,0,64,64))
fakeScreen = screen.copy()
testSurface = pygame.Surface((512,512))

screenScrollX = 0
screenScrollY = 0

### Классы ###
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(skinsPath, "default-1.png"))
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (64, 64))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (128,128)

    def moveRight(self):
        global screenScrollX
        if not self.rect.right > 512:
            self.rect.x += 4
            # screenScrollX -= 8
    
    def moveLeft(self):
        global screenScrollX
        if not self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.x -= 4
            # screenScrollX += 8
    
    def moveUp(self):
        global screenScrollY
        if not self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.y -= 4
            # screenScrollY += 8
    
    def moveDown(self):
        global screenScrollY
        if not self.rect.bottom > 512:
            self.rect.y += 4
            # screenScrollY -= 8
    
    def moveLeftDown(self):
        global screenScrollX, screenScrollY
        if not self.rect.bottom > 512:
            if not self.rect.left < 0:
                self.rect.y += 4
                # screenScrollY -= 8
                self.rect.x -= 4
                # screenScrollX += 8

    def moveLeftUp(self):
        global screenScrollX, screenScrollY
        if not self.rect.top < 0:
            if not self.rect.left < 0:
                self.rect.y -= 4
                # screenScrollY += 8
                self.rect.x -= 4
                # screenScrollX += 8

    def moveRightDown(self):
        global screenScrollX, screenScrollY
        if not self.rect.bottom > 512:
            if not self.rect.right > 512:
                self.rect.y += 4
                # screenScrollY -= 8
                self.rect.x += 4
                # screenScrollX -= 8

    def moveRightUp(self):
        global screenScrollX, screenScrollY
        self.rect.y -= 4
        # screenScrollY += 8
        self.rect.x += 4
        # screenScrollX -= 8


player = Player()
allSprites.add(player)

def mainMenu():
    global motion
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)
        
        screen.fill((0,0,0))

        posX, posY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                motion = "stop"
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    if grid1.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        boxSprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
                        boxSprite.image = box
                        boxSprite.rect = box.get_rect()
                        boxSprite.rect.x = 0
                        boxSprite.rect.y = 0
                        allSprites.add(boxSprite)
                    else:
                        boxSprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
                        boxSprite.image = box
                        boxSprite.rect = box.get_rect()
                        boxSprite.rect.x = posX
                        boxSprite.rect.y = posY
                        allSprites.add(boxSprite)
                
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        
        #moving
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]:
            motion = "left"
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]:
            motion = "right"
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_w]:
            motion = "up"
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_s]:
            motion = "down"
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and keys[K_UP]:
            motion = "leftup"
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and keys[K_DOWN]:
            motion = "leftdown"
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and keys[K_UP]:
            motion = "rightup"
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and keys[K_DOWN]:
            motion = "rightdown"

        if motion == "left":
            player.moveLeft()
        if motion == "right":
            player.moveRight()
        if motion == "up":
            player.moveUp()
        if motion == "down":
            player.moveDown()

        if motion == "leftup":
            player.moveLeftUp()
        if motion == "leftdown":
            player.moveLeftDown()
        if motion == "rightup":
            player.moveRightUp()
        if motion == "rightdown":   
            player.moveRightDown()

        # screen.blit(player, (0,0))
        fakeScreen.blit(ground512, (0,0))
        allSprites.update()
        allSprites.draw(fakeScreen)
        text2 = font1.render(str(int(clock.get_fps())), False,
                  (255, 255, 255))
        fakeScreen.blit(text2, (0,0))
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(fakeScreen, (512, 512)), (screenScrollX,screenScrollY))
        pygame.display.flip()

mainMenu()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Интик мне хочется сделать "прилипание" к координатам, если было кликнуто в любые координаты в пределах границ клетки.

Comment: Можете помочь реализовать эту систему как ответ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

подправить пришлось всего 2 строчки и чуть проще чем писал в комментариях (не нужна была середина спрайта)

```
boxSprite.rect.x = (posX//64)*64
boxSprite.rect.y = (posY//64)*64
```

и на будущее выкладывайте и картинки тоже, гомерчика самому пришлось рисовать ) normalbox.png

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import os
import sys

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

motion = "stop"

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((512, 512))
pygame.display.set_caption('Main Menu - Limited Space, Endless Ideas')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

### Настраиваем директории ###
rootPath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
resourcesPath = os.path.join(rootPath, "resources")
texturesPath = os.path.join(resourcesPath, "textures")
playerPath = os.path.join(texturesPath, "player")
skinsPath = os.path.join(playerPath, "skins")

### Настраиваем пути текстур ###
ground512 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(texturesPath, "ground512x512.png"))
box = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(texturesPath, "normalbox.png"))
box = pygame.transform.scale(box, (64, 64))
boxSprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
boxSprite.image = box
boxSprite.rect = box.get_rect()

### Настраиваем шрифт ###
font1 = pygame.font.Font('font.ttf', 36)

grid1 = pygame.Rect((0, 0, 64, 64))
fakeScreen = screen.copy()
testSurface = pygame.Surface((512, 512))

screenScrollX = 0
screenScrollY = 0


### Классы ###
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(skinsPath, "default-1.png"))
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (64, 64))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (128, 128)

    def moveRight(self):
        global screenScrollX
        if not self.rect.right > 512:
            self.rect.x += 4
            # screenScrollX -= 8

    def moveLeft(self):
        global screenScrollX
        if not self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.x -= 4
            # screenScrollX += 8

    def moveUp(self):
        global screenScrollY
        if not self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.y -= 4
            # screenScrollY += 8

    def moveDown(self):
        global screenScrollY
        if not self.rect.bottom > 512:
            self.rect.y += 4
            # screenScrollY -= 8

    def moveLeftDown(self):
        global screenScrollX, screenScrollY
        if not self.rect.bottom > 512:
            if not self.rect.left < 0:
                self.rect.y += 4
                # screenScrollY -= 8
                self.rect.x -= 4
                # screenScrollX += 8

    def moveLeftUp(self):
        global screenScrollX, screenScrollY
        if not self.rect.top < 0:
            if not self.rect.left < 0:
                self.rect.y -= 4
                # screenScrollY += 8
                self.rect.x -= 4
                # screenScrollX += 8

    def moveRightDown(self):
        global screenScrollX, screenScrollY
        if not self.rect.bottom > 512:
            if not self.rect.right > 512:
                self.rect.y += 4
                # screenScrollY -= 8
                self.rect.x += 4
                # screenScrollX -= 8

    def moveRightUp(self):
        global screenScrollX, screenScrollY
        self.rect.y -= 4
        # screenScrollY += 8
        self.rect.x += 4
        # screenScrollX -= 8


player = Player()
allSprites.add(player)


def mainMenu():
    global motion
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        posX, posY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                motion = "stop"
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    if grid1.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        boxSprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
                        boxSprite.image = box
                        boxSprite.rect = box.get_rect()
                        boxSprite.rect.x = 0
                        boxSprite.rect.y = 0
                        allSprites.add(boxSprite)
                    else:
                        boxSprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
                        boxSprite.image = box
                        boxSprite.rect = box.get_rect()
                        print(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
                        boxSprite.rect.x = (posX//64)*64    #изменения тут
                        boxSprite.rect.y = (posY//64)*64    #и тут
                        print(boxSprite.rect.x,boxSprite.rect.y)
                        allSprites.add(boxSprite)

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        # moving
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]:
            motion = "left"
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]:
            motion = "right"
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_w]:
            motion = "up"
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_s]:
            motion = "down"
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and keys[K_UP]:
            motion = "leftup"
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and keys[K_DOWN]:
            motion = "leftdown"
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and keys[K_UP]:
            motion = "rightup"
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and keys[K_DOWN]:
            motion = "rightdown"

        if motion == "left":
            player.moveLeft()
        if motion == "right":
            player.moveRight()
        if motion == "up":
            player.moveUp()
        if motion == "down":
            player.moveDown()

        if motion == "leftup":
            player.moveLeftUp()
        if motion == "leftdown":
            player.moveLeftDown()
        if motion == "rightup":
            player.moveRightUp()
        if motion == "rightdown":
            player.moveRightDown()

        # screen.blit(player, (0,0))
        fakeScreen.blit(ground512, (0, 0))
        allSprites.update()
        allSprites.draw(fakeScreen)
        text2 = font1.render(str(int(clock.get_fps())), False,
                             (255, 255, 255))
        fakeScreen.blit(text2, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(fakeScreen, (512, 512)), (screenScrollX, screenScrollY))
        pygame.display.flip()


mainMenu()
```

результат

[image: result]

Comment: А если у меня будет другой размер сетки, например 10x12?

Comment: там нужен размер клетки. если больше клеток, то не важно